# Tech Stack for a vector graphic editor app?

Tags: android, python, java, vector-graphics

I am a Flutter Developer and Know Basics of Java. I want to make a Vector Graphic Editor App like:
[Infinity Design](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brakefield.idfree&hl=en_IN).

What tech stack should I use? Is Java enough for this? If yes can you please recommend any android library/API/Plugin for this.

Or I should use something like Python for image editing and Java or Flutter for Android UI?

> I am ready to learn any language necessary for this. But I didn't have
>   about where to start and how to start.

Comment: Please note that asking for programming languages is off-topic here. For details, see: [Should programming language recommendations be allowed here?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185)